# PHP function not returning any information when passed via return, but will happily echo within the function

Tags: php, json, function, return-value, ld

I'm wondering if someone could help me out with a function I'm writing.  Basically I'm trying to search through some JSON-LD data for a specific key.  The JSON-LD data has been assigned to an array using json_decode.  The array looks like this but could have a different format and structure:

```
{ 
   "@context":"https://schema.org",
   "@graph":[ 
      { 
         "@type":"Organization",
         "@id":"https://www.web.site/#organization",
         "name":"Some Name",
         "url":"https://www.web.site/",
         "sameAs":[ 
            "https://www.facebook.com/website",
            "https://www.linkedin.com/company/website",
            "https://twitter.com/website"
         ],
         "logo":{ 
            "@type":"ImageObject",
            "@id":"https://www.web.site/#logo",
            "inLanguage":"en",
            "url":"https://web.site/logo.svg",
            "width":200,
            "height":100,
            "caption":"Some Name"
         },
         "image":{ 
            "@id":"https://www.web.site/#logo"
         }
      },
      { 
         "@type":"WebSite",
         "@id":"https://www.web.site/#website",
         "url":"https://www.web.site/",
         "name":"Some Name",
         "inLanguage":"en",
         "description":"Some description here.",
         "publisher":{ 
            "@id":"https://www.web.site/#organization"
         },
         "potentialAction":[ 
            { 
               "@type":"SearchAction",
               "target":"https://www.web.site/?s={search_term_string}",
               "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
            }
         ]
      },
      { 
         "@type":"WebPage",
         "@id":"https://www.web.site/#webpage",
         "url":"https://www.web.site/",
         "name":"Some Name",
         "isPartOf":{ 
            "@id":"https://www.web.site/#website"
         },
         "inLanguage":"en",
         "about":{ 
            "@id":"https://www.web.site/#organization"
         },
         "datePublished":"2017-01-01T21:21:21+00:00",
         "dateModified":"2017-01-01T21:21:21+00:00",
         "description":"Some description here.",
         "potentialAction":[ 
            { 
               "@type":"ReadAction",
               "target":[ 
                  "https://www.web.site/"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The function I have written to find a key looks like this:

```
function findArrayKey($array, $find) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if((string)$key == $find){
                foreach($value as $key => $value) {
                    $info .= $value;
                }
            } else {      
                findArrayKey($value,$find);
            }
        }
    }
    echo $info; // prints the info
    return $info; // returns nothing
}                      

echo findArrayKey($myarray,$keyimlookingfor);
```

The echo findArrayKey line at the bottom just does nothing (I've also tried var_dump and print_r and still get nothing) yet the echo within the function works perfectly.

The output from the echo within the function is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/websitehttps://www.linkedin.com/company/websitehttps://twitter.com/website
```

The output from the echo outside it (with the data passed back via return) is blank..

Any help someone could provide would be greatly appreciated, thank you for everything in advance.

Comment: To be clear, if you echo the function call with just return enabled within the function you get nothing?

Comment: @JayBlanchard that is correct

Comment: You make a recursive call but discard its return value.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález would you have any idea how to fix it then? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `$info .= findArrayKey($value,$find);`

Comment: @NigelRen that did it!! Thank you very much, your help is greatly appreciated.